# Admob + surfaceview don't play well

Tags: java, android, emulation, admob, surfaceview

I'm running Admob 6.0.1 and trying to add the advert over the top of the surface view, I can say that the code below works great with a Android 3.2 (a real device), and also works fine with a android 4 device in the emulator but, when I try to test on pre api13, eg 2.3.3 or below the advert doesn't show. Now here's the weird part, if I change the visibility of the surfaceview (in xml) to invisible the advert will show!!!! what's going on?? Is this just the emulator being buggy or do I have a real problem?

I've tried to keep the code as simple as possible to reproduce the error. I've added a button just to show the surfaceview does allow other views to update, just not the Admob view...

```
   package com.google.example.ads.fundamentals;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;

    import com.google.ads.AdView;

    public class BannerSample extends Activity {
    /** The view to show the ad. */
    private AdView adView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    }

    class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final TutorialThread _thread;

    public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet att) {
        super(context, att);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        Log.d("Hello", "drawing stuff");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        Log.d("HELLO", "surface changed" + holder.getSurfaceFrame().width()
                + "Height: " + holder.getSurfaceFrame().height());

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or
        // else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }
    }

    class TutorialThread extends Thread {
    private final SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private final Panel _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public TutorialThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    _panel.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.example.ads.fundamentals.Panel
        android:id="@+id/mainPanel" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:visibility="invisible" />
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" ads:adSize="BANNER"         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/mybutton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/adView"
        android:text="hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.google.example.ads.fundamentals"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BannerSample"
                              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Any ideas or help would be so great, I've tried to post on Google Groups for admob but I think it got lost in a void..

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out it was a problem with the emulator, When the code was run on a real device it worked fine! crazy emulator...

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `AdView` outside of the `SurfaceView` instead of on top of it.  You can do this by aligning the `AdView` ad the top, and setting the `SurfaceView` below it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.example.ads.fundamentals.Panel
        android:id="@+id/mainPanel" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView" />
   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Has anyone got Mediation working with a SurfaceView running pre android 3.2? If I use normal Admob integration, (no mediation) the adverts display, but when I swap the  Publisher ID  to a Mediation ID:  the adverts will not load, but if I then remove the surface view they will again!

I've managed to get this similar code working with inmobi, tapfortap, normal admob, but the moment I try to use mediation it fails on pre 3.2, ics work fine. 

So I truly think this is a bug in the mediation framework, I don't think this is something simple, as I've had no problems with other similar integrations